# How to select all values that are not numeric across multiple columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I have one table `Prices`

```
ID Price_1 Price_2 Price_3

P1 10      11      12
P2 13      14      15
P3 aa      16      bb
P4 19      cc      20
```

---

As you can see from above, some values from columns `Price_1`, `Price_2` and `Price_3` might not be numeric.

What I want is that first all find all those `non-numeric values` and then give an summary (`concatenate` all non-numeric values and columns for one id)

So for the above example, what I want is

```
ID   Bad_Columns      Bad_Values
P3   Price_1,Price_3  aa,bb
P4   Price_2          cc
```

---

How should i write this query?

Comment: Ok, if you want to have some kind of audit table with bad values for columns, then I strongly recommend that you do **not** concatenate those values, no point on doing that on your database. You could have that same table with one row per bad value per column.

Comment: @Lamak thanks for your advices. I just need to produce a summary table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  ID, Value, ColumnName
    FROM    Prices
            UNPIVOT
            (   Value
                FOR ColumnName IN ([Price_1], [Price_2], [Price_3])
            ) upvt
    WHERE   ISNUMERIC(Value) = 0
)
SELECT  ID,
        BadColumns = STUFF((SELECT  ', ' + ColumnName 
                            FROM    CTE
                            WHERE   CTE.ID = t.ID
                            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, ''),
        BadValues = STUFF(( SELECT  ', ' + Value 
                            FROM    CTE
                            WHERE   CTE.ID = t.ID
                            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM CTE) t
```

The first part UNPIVOTs your query to get columns as rows, then the second part will concatenate the "bad" rows into one column.

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f3a3/6)**

Comment: sorry, I have added bad_columns as well, how to adapt to that?

Comment: can I use `WITH...AS...` inside a trigger? I got error: `Incorrect syntax near 'CTE'.`

Comment: There is no problem using it inside a trigger, You need to ensure that the line before `WITH` is terminated with a semi-colon (or put a semi-colon before the `WITH`).

Comment: after the last select, should again terminate?

Comment: Yes, although this should not make too much difference.

Comment: ok, what if the `prices` table has an extra `name` column which is not unique and I want to include name column in the final summary table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following which will *unpivot* the data and then concatenate the values using `FOR XML PATH`:

```
;with cte as
(
  select id, col, data
  from
  (
    select t.id,
      c.col,
      case c.col
        when 'Price_1' then Price_1
        when 'Price_2' then Price_2
        when 'Price_3' then Price_3
      end as data
    from yourtable t
    cross join
    (
      select 'Price_1' as col
      union all select 'Price_2'
      union all select 'Price_3'
    ) c
  ) src
  where isnumeric(data) = 0
)
select distinct c1.id,
  stuff((select ', ' + col
         from cte c2
         where c1.id = c2.id
         FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS Bad_columns,
  stuff((select ', ' + data
         from cte c2
         where c1.id = c2.id
         FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS Bad_Values
from cte c1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/957cd/11).

This can also be written using the `unpivot` function:

```
;with cte as
(
  select id, col, data
  from yourtable
  unpivot
  (
    data
    for col in ([Price_1], [Price_2], [Price_3])
  ) unpiv
  where isnumeric(data) = 0
)
select distinct c1.id,
  stuff((select ', ' + col
         from cte c2
         where c1.id = c2.id
         FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS Bad_columns,
  stuff((select ', ' + data
         from cte c2
         where c1.id = c2.id
         FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS Bad_Values
from cte c1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/957cd/12). The result is:

```
| ID |       BAD_COLUMNS | BAD_VALUES |
---------------------------------------
| P3 |  Price_1, Price_3 |     aa, bb |
| P4 |           Price_2 |         cc |
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
select p.*
from ((select id, price_1 as price, 'price_1' as col) union all
      (select id, price_2 as price, 'price_2' as col) union all
      (select id, price_3 as price, 'price_3' as col)
     ) p
where is_numeric(price) = 0 and price is not null
```

If you actually want them in the format you have, just do:

```
select id,
       stuff((case when isnumeric(price_1) = 1 then ',Price_1' else '' end) +
             (case when isnumeric(price_2) = 1 then ',Price_2' else '' end) +
             (case when isnumeric(price_3) = 1 then ',Price_3' else '' end)
            ), 1, 1, '') as Bad_Columns,
       stuff((case when isnumeric(price_1) = 1 then ','+Price_1 else '' end) +
             (case when isnumeric(price_2) = 1 then ','+Price_2 else '' end) +
             (case when isnumeric(price_3) = 1 then ','+Price_3 else '' end)
            ), 1, 1, '') as Bad_Values
from p
where isnumeric(price_1) = 0 or isnumeric(price_2)= 0 or isnumeric(price_3) = 0
```

The reason that I'm not using `unpivot` is because that assumes that the column types are compatible.  If you want to extend this to more columns, use Excel to generate the code.